# Issue with search functionality using Linq

Tags: asp.net-mvc, linq, asp.net-mvc-3, entity-framework

I have got a keyword column in my products table , keyword column will have keywords like for instance red , green , white , purple , black. Each product has a keyword. I want a key word dropdownlist in the my search option so , that when black keyword is selected all the products which has a keyword black should be displayed, Is it possible to achieve something like this , if yes any assistance or help will be highly appreciated??

Also I want to populate the dropdown list with keyword column for instance if the new product with different keywords is added the dropdownlist should include that keyword too.

Currently I am using manufacture for searching , below is the code :
View:

```
@if (Model.AvailableManufacturers.Count > 0)
                            {
                                <tr>
                                    <td class="title">
                                        @Html.LabelFor(model => model.Mid):
                                    </td>
                                    <td class="data">
                                        @Html.DropDownListFor(model => model.Mid, Model.AvailableManufacturers)
                                    </td>
                                </tr>
                            }
```

Controller:

```
var manufacturers = _manufacturerService.GetAllManufacturers();
        if (manufacturers.Count > 0)
        {
            model.AvailableManufacturers.Add(new SelectListItem()
            {
                Value = "0",
                Text = _localizationService.GetResource("Common.All")
            });
            foreach (var m in manufacturers)
                model.AvailableManufacturers.Add(new SelectListItem()
                {
                    Value = m.Id.ToString(),
                    Text = m.Name,
                    Selected = model.Mid == m.Id
                });
        }
```

ManufactureService.cs:

```
      public virtual IList<Manufacturer> GetAllManufacturers(bool showHidden = false)
    {

            var query = from m in _manufacturerRepository.Table
                        orderby m.DisplayOrder
                        where (showHidden || m.Published) &&
                        !m.Deleted
                        select m;
            var manufacturers = query.ToList();
            return manufacturers;

    }
```

Question : What Linq Query should i use to call the distinct keywords from the table product and populate that in the dropdownlist.

Question 2 : Sql query for searching the products of selected keyword.

I am using mvc3 razor and LINQ

Answer (score 1):

This should give you a distinct list of keywords assuming you can reference your product table directly. If you can only reference products via a manufacturer we'll need to alter it a bit.

```
var availableKeywords = productTable.Select(product => product.Keyword).Distinct();
```

You could then pass those keywords as a select list to your view via ViewData as follows:

```
ViewData["Keywords"] = new SelectList(availableKeywords);
```

As for then using a selected keyword via a drop down list to filter the products table could you do something like the following?:

```
var matchingProducts = productTable.Where(product => product.Keyword == selectedKeywordFromDropDown);
```

You'll just need to make sure your action method accesses the passed in keyword from the drop down via a parameter or from the Request object.